# .NET Excel Pivot Table

Tags: asp.net, database, excel, pivot-table

Is there a way to create a PivotTable in Excel **from a database connection** using C# or VB.NET? I have done so using the Interop classes as suggested in the link here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/07/25/creating-a-pivottable-programmatically.aspx

The problem is that I can't use that method as my application is Web Based and I can't make the assumption that Excel will always be installed. Microsoft also says that the Interop classes aren't supposed to be used in a server environment.

I've looked at the Open XML SDK and have seen that it supports the PivotCache functionality, but so far I have yet to find any example. I have seen many other tools such as EPPlus and Gembox that allows to create the PivotTable, but as far as I have seen none of them can create the database connection in Excel.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is close to impossible pr unnecessarily difficult. I ended up coding the necessary instructions in VBA and inserting the instructions into an Excel Document using EPPlus. Works perfectly :)